# Data visualization with qt and qtopengl

Tags: data-visualization, qtopengl

I understand that "Data visualization or data visualisation is the creation and study of the visual representation of data, meaning "information that has been abstracted in some schematic form, including attributes or variables for the units of information".

And now...It's a quite strange question, but...I'd like to make a (very) simple programme with qt and qtopengl- a cube, whose vertexes have RGB-coordinates, I mean its colours (0,0,0; 0,255,0 and so on). Will this programme illustrate data visualization (maybe just a little...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could class that as data visualisation if you layer some meaning over the coordinates of your cube. Say for example, the furthest a point is from some reference point on the cube, the darker the colour is of that point.

For some excellent examples of data visualisation techniques and examples, please have a look at [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) website.